# Scala Slick MySQL - performing advanced SQL stuff

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick-2.0

I have 3 tables in my MySQL db: applications, users and application_images. 
I need to write a query that will generate the next SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM applications 
JOIN users ON applications.user_id=users.id 
LEFT JOIN applications_images ON applications_images.app_id=applications.id
WHERE applications.id=?
```

How can this be achieved with the slick syntax?

And on the same subject: How can I write plain SQL queries with slick (on MySQL DB)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `leftJoin`, you use the `?` method to project the table to an `Option`.  Yours might look something like:

```
applications join users on (_.user_id === _.id) map { 
    case (app, user) => (app, user) 
} leftJoin application_images on (_._1.id === _.app_id) map {
    case ((app, user), image) => (app, user, image.?)
} filter(_._1.id === {id})
```

Comment: Thanks, the only thing that should be changed is the order of the fields in the leftJoin. The correct answer is applications join users on (_.user_id === _.id) map { 
    case (app, user) => (app, user) 
} leftJoin application_images on (_._1.id ===_.app_id) map {
    case ((app, user), image) => (app, user, image.?)
} filter(_._1.id === {id})